# C++ fstream in >> variableName execution

Tags: c++, fstream

Here is my code, not sure why no error but return nothing. it is OK if there is no getline function in ReadFile?? And when debugging, another potential problem is whether the map is needed to define the size when map is declared. I am a beginner. any help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<map>
#include<set>
#include<string>    

void swap(char &ch1, char &ch2){ //swap the content
    char tmp=ch1;
    ch1=ch2;
    ch2=tmp;
}

std::string ToLower(std::string s){
    for(int i=0;i < s.length();i++)
    {
        if(s[i]<='Z' && s[i]>='A')
        {
            s[i]-='A'-'a';
        }
    }
    return s;
}

std::string signature(std::string s)
{
    s=ToLower(s);
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {   int minIndex=i;

        for(int j=i+1;j<s.length();j++)
            if(s[j]<s[minIndex]) minIndex=j;
        swap(s[minIndex],s[i]);
    }
    return s;
}

void ReadFile(std::ifstream &in, std::map<std::string,std::set<std::string>> &m)
{
    while(true)
    {
        std::string word;
        in>>word;
        if(!in.good())break;
        m[signature(word)].insert(word);
    }
}
typedef std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>>::const_iterator MapIterator;
 typedef std::set<std::string>::const_iterator SetIterator;

int main(){
    std::ifstream in("ospd.txt");
    std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>> m;
    ReadFile(in,m);     


for (MapIterator iter = m.begin(); iter != m.end(); iter++)
{
    std::cout << "Key: " << iter->first << std::endl << "Values:" << std::endl;

    for (SetIterator set_iter = iter->second.begin(); set_iter != iter->second.end(); set_iter++)
        std::cout << " " << *set_iter <<std:: endl;
}

    system("pause");
return 0;}
```

Updated: the programming is working. Thanks for everybody!!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this.

```
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;


void ReadFile(std::ifstream &in, std::map<std::string,std::set<std::string>> &m)
    istream_iterator<string> itr(in);
    istream_iterator<string> end;
    while(itr != end)
    {
        string work = *itr;
        m[signature(word)].insert(word);
        ++itr;
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking a question or answering the question? If you're doing the former, you should consider posting this as a comment.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working. But I do need add the iterator header. Thanks @VishalKumar

Comment: @0x499602D2 its is suggestion. I should have mentioned that. Thanks for pointing out. As for program correctness, try giving full path. Looks like call could not find ospd.txt. You can confirm this with in.is_open. I am sure it will return 0 with current program. You do not need to make any other changes.

Comment: Please post this as a comment with a link to the code (maybe on [Ideone](http://ideone.com)).